# Why is the If done before the forEach ends?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code i take data from firebase and put it in array then i want to check array size but array size check is done before i finish filling array
Thanks for the helpers

```
componentDidMount() {
console.log("MyOrder componentDidMount");
this.setState({order:[]})
var user = Firebase.auth().currentUser;
db.collection("request")
  .where("getUid", "==", user.uid)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        db.collection("users").doc(doc.data().postUid).get().then(doc2=>{
            console.log("ggggggggggggggg")
            var a = this.state.order;
            var b=doc.data()
            b.phone=doc2.data().phone
            a.push(b);
            this.setState({ order: a });
        })

    });
    if (this.state.order.length == 0) 
    {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    } 
    else 
    {
      var size=this.state.order.length
      var arry=[]
      for(let i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
        console.log(i)
        arry.push(this.state.order[i])
      }
      this.setState({ order: arry });
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      this.setState({ c: true });
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That is because your array fill happen in the then block of API response which is asynchronous. And before the API responds array size code is executed... If you are not getting my explanation, please go through Promises concepts in JavaScript.

**Solutions**

1. Wrap the array size checking code in a function and call that function and call that function at the end of then block.
2. Use async await combination to move on the array size check after API responds.